# How randomized array keys with rand() works?

Tags: php, arrays, random

I'm a bit confused about how this works (the title)?
For example, i'm setting an array like this

```
$array[rand(0, 5)] = 'Alex';
$array[rand(0, 5)] = 'Blue';
$array[rand(0, 5)] = 'Dale';
$array[rand(0, 5)] = 'Matt';
```

An example of a possible result after a `var_dump($array);` of the array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Blue
    [1] => Dale
    [2] => Matt
)
```

What happens technically?

Comment: you constructing array with random key for each value .rand(0,5) means it take any one between 0-5 but may be key overwriting issue is here . its the best example . run this one more than one time and know the each output .you can see the key repeating <?php
$array1[rand(0, 5)] = 'Alex';
$array2[rand(0, 5)] = 'Blue';
$array3[rand(0, 5)] = 'Dale';
$array4[rand(0, 5)] = 'Matt';

print_r($array1);
print_r($array2);
print_r($array3);
print_r($array4);

?>

Comment: Ok. That is because the repeated value of the randomized, but what about the other values? Should i to use the array function to keep the other value but with another keys ?

Comment: your not able to store the same key for another value so that array value are omitted

Comment: try this  $ss = array('1'=>'sdfdsf','1'=>'oooo');  print_r($ss); here you can see only last   inserted  value in this array .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your constructing array with random key for each value .rand(0,5) means it take any one number between 0-5 but may be key overwriting issue is here . 
its the best example . run this one more than one time and know the each output .you can see the key repeating

```
    <?php 

    $array1[rand(0, 5)] = 'Alex'; 
    $array2[rand(0, 5)] = 'Blue'; 
    $array3[rand(0, 5)] = 'Dale'; 
    $array4[rand(0, 5)] = 'Matt'; 

    print_r($array1); 
    print_r($array2); 
    print_r($array3); 
    print_r($array4); 


    output:

    out put differ each time .here you can see the key repetation . 

        Array ( [4] => Alex ) 
        Array ( [3] => Blue ) 
        Array ( [4] => Dale ) 
        Array ( [5] => Matt ) 
    ?>
```

Comment: Ok, then i'm forced to use an associative array or predefined keys to keep all values in the array, right?

Comment: you can use anything .if you want keep the all values means .your key should be unique for each value

Comment: That is, that was the doubt about. Thanks @jothi

Answer (score 0):

Consider the example below :

```
$array[0] = 'Alex';  //replaced  rand(0, 5) with 0
$array[3] = 'Blue';  //replaced  rand(0, 5) with 3
$array[2] = 'Dale';  //replaced  rand(0, 5) with 2
$array[4] = 'Matt';  //replaced  rand(0, 5) with 4

var_dump($array);
```

We have the output as below without any change :

[image]

When you use `rand(0, 5)` it takes random value given , hence it keeps changing each time you run and you have different outputs.

`var_dump` — Dumps information about a variable

More info on [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Comment: Thanks @tharif for the enriching explanation! :)